# How to update ProgressBar during a long external operation?

Tags: .net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

In my .NET app, I am reading a large SQL table into memory, and I would like the `ProgressBar` in the app's window to progress, at least somewhat, while the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` operation is blocking. I already have the `Fill()` call in the background thread of a `BackgroundWorker` object, and I tried to update the `ProgressBar` in the foreground thread which called `RunWorkerAsync()` but that is not working. Any suggestions here?

Comment: You aren't going to get progress from Fill. You could try OnRowUpdating / Updated, or just go for a simple animation based on a timer. How you work out how much progress has been made though, depends on what you are doing. If it's this heavy getting a count might be heavy as well.

Comment: I realize there is no update from `Fill()`. What I tried to do is  animate the `ProgressBar` in the foreground thread while the background thread was performing the `Fill()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Might have out thought yourself. Just kick a timer off when the fill starts and stop when it's done.

Comment: @Tony - the Timer did it. If you submit as an answer, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you can't get progress from Dataset.Fill, directly and using OnRowUpdate / OnRowUpdated is painful and you still won't get % done out of it unles you find out how many rows should be updated.

Might as well just bang a timer on there and update some animation while the Fill Task is running.

As a side note we wrote a little animation component, that runs in it own thread that you pass the method you want to want execute in a thread. Wraps it all up nicely and you can put the thing inside a using block and be all neat and tidy. Works well for fire and forget threads, and you can do a modal version as well.